# Is this a ground wire in my ceiling light canopy?

Tags: grounding

I just installed a ceiling light fixture, which has a feature I've never seen before. The fixture has the traditional white, black, and green wires. I attached the white and black fixture wires to the corresponding black and white source wires, and the green fixture wire to the bare copper source wire.

The unfamiliar feature is that the canopy has a twisted copper wire attached to it, on the inside. I included this wire with the bare copper and green wire connection, assuming it was another ground wire. Now I'm not sure about it. Should I have just left it unattached?

Answer (score 1):

If it was a bare wire it definitely was a grounding wire. Considering your description I can only assume it was there to bond the canopy.